# How to check if the program is running with Administrator privileges in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, windows-7, uac, administration

Is there any way to check in JavaScript if the current program runs with administrative privileges?

For example in C# i can do it with the following code:

```
bool isRunningWithAdminApprovals;
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
isRunningWithAdminApprovals = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

However I need to check it with a current running script of javaScript.
If i try to run an exe or a wrapper of the C# code, the UAC will prompt me to approve it and then i will already be in Administrative privilages...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers, the Javascript environment is run in a sandbox, so there's no way you can know anything about the system except those things that the browser put in the sandbox, ie the user agent string and a little more.

I fear you have to rely on other techniques, like Flash or Java, then retrieve the value with Javascript.

Comment: OP may be talking about running a .js script outside of a web browser, in which case, it probably isn't sandboxed.

Comment: Except the post is tagged with "browser"